# Anaconda Navigator not launching on OSX

Tags: macos, python-3.x, anaconda

I recently installed Anaconda 4.3.0 on my Macbook, running OSX EL Capitan 10.11.1. I tried to launching the 'Anaconda Navigator' but it crashes upon launching it. I tried online help and nothing really works. Users tell me to update my bash profile [file](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/910), but i really have no idea on where to find this bash profile file. Please explain in layman's terms

Answer (score 0):

Had the same trouble and I couldn't do something to change the situation except reinstalled Anaconda navigator on mac(OS EL Capitan 10.11.6). BTW, symptoms the same as you described "it crashes upon launching it". Try reinstalling the Anaconda Navigator; hope someone will give you more reasonable answer. Good Luck